# Gatling recording is not passing required cookie to each get request

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, gatling

I've recorded a test using the Gatling recorder. But at each .get request the script redirects to the home page/base url because the cookie isn't being passed.  How can I save the cookie then pass it into each .get call?? I've read the Gatling documentation for HTTP Helpers but it's not very specific. I'm obviously new to Gatling. Thanks!

Here is some example code:

```scala
private val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("https://branch3.coverageforcompanies.com")


  private val scn = scenario("AgentTest")
    .exec(
      http("Open C4C on Chrome")
        .get("/")
        .headers(headers_0)
        
    )
    .pause(5)
    .exec(
      http("Enter Agent email and password")
        .post("/")
        .headers(headers_4)
        .formParam("_token", "sometoken")
        .formParam("username", "someemail.com")
        .formParam("password", "somepassword")
        .resources(
          http("Click on Sign in and bring up dashboard")
            .get("/a/dashboard")
            .headers(headers_5),
            pause(5)
    .exec(
      http("Click on My Book Link")
        .get("/a/mybook")
        .headers(headers_5)
```

The redirect from the second .get (.get"/a/mybook") has a 302 response and redirects to the home page. Here is a sample result from the log file:

```
Request:
Click on My Book Link: OK 
=========================
Session:
Session(AgentTest,1,HashMap(gatling.http.cache.baseUrl ->https://baseurl.com, gatling.http.ssl.sslContexts 
GET https://branch3.coverageforcompanies.com/a/mybook

cookies:
    XSRF-TOKEN=token number
    laravel_session=laravel session number
=========================
HTTP response:
status:
    302 Found
    
    headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Location: https://baseurl.com
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
    Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=token number
    
    Set-Cookie: laravel_session = laravel session number
    Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2022 18:00:10 GMT
    content-length: 406
    
    Request:
Click on My Book Link Redirect 1: OK 
=========================
Session:
Session(AgentTest,1,HashMap(gatling.http.cache.baseUrl -> https://baseurl.com, gatling.http.ssl.sslContexts ->
=========================
HTTP request:
GET https://baseurl.com
headers:
```

Answer (score 0):

Gatling handles cookies for you at runtime, as long as the server sets them as part of the flow.

Gatling's Recorder won't record your existing cookies that were set prior to starting the recording for good reasons: cookies have an expiration date, and should usually not be shared amongst multiple virtual users. You want to have your Gatling tests replayable, not suddenly break because a recorded cookie has expired.

You must include your login steps in your scenario so that your Gatling virtual users can receive a cookie from the server.

You should probably record in browser anonymous mode to bypass any previously stored cookie.

Comment: Do you have an example of login steps receiving cookies from the server. This is an application test not an api test. Also, I did record the script in incognito mode. Thanks!

Comment: I'm saving a HAR file then converting it using the recorder. Could that be the issue?

Comment: No. The recorder ignores the Cookie header, period. Does your recording includes the request whose response sets the cookie in the browser?

Comment: The recording does include the request where the cookie is set. The issue is when there's a redirect/302 at a .get gatling goes back to the home page. So it appears the cookie isn't being passed in at the .get. So I wanted to pass in the cookie with the .get call to stop the redirect if possible.

Comment: Gatling handles cookies during redirects. Which version of Gatling are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version 3.7.6 But the session ID needs to be passed in each request to ensure the user is logged in.  Otherwise the redirect goes to the base url or home page.

Comment: Impossible to investigate and help you unless you provide a reproducer as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added some example code and log file results. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: `branch3.coverageforcompanies.com` is not a public hostname, so there's no way to reproduce. Then, your `.formParam("_token", "sometoken")` with a static value is very suspicious. It's most likely a nonce non-replayable token that you have to save from the previous response with a check.

Comment: It was the _token! I had to extract it, save it in a variable then use the variable in the forParm. Thanks again for the help!